# PMF : Determine the distribution function of X

Tags: probability, functions, probability-distributions

The spectrum of a discrete random variable X consists of the points 1, 2, 3,..., n  and its probability mass function (pmf) fi = P(X = i) is proportional to 1/i(i+1). Determine the distribution function of X. Further, compute P(3 < X <= n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
&\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{1 \over i\left(i + 1\right)}
=
\sum_{i = 1}^{n}\left({1 \over i} - {1 \over i + 1}\right)
=
\left(1 - {1 \over 2}\right) + \left({1 \over 2} - {1 \over 3}\right)
+
\cdots
+
\left({1 \over n} - {1 \over n + 1}\right)
\\[3mm]&=
1 - {1 \over n + 1} = {n \over n + 1}
\end{align}

$$\color{#ff0000}{\large%
P = {n + 1\over n}\,{1 \over i\left(i + 1\right)}}
$$

Next and last question:

$$\color{#ff0000}{\large%
{n + 1 \over n}\,\left(%
1 - {1 \over 2} - {1 \over 6} - {1 \over 12}\right)
=
{1 \over 4}\,{n + 1 \over n}}
$$

Comment: Hi Felix ... $$\sum_{i = 1}^{n}{1 \over i\left(i + 1\right)} = n/(n+1)$$ ...  not $(n-1)/n$.  The other results update accordingly.

Comment: @wolfies Thanks. I already checked. I guess I'm tired. I even forget the $\mbox{\cdots}$ $\left(\cdots\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

I normally try not to answer homework problems, but (a) in this case the other posted solution has some errors, and (b) I am posting the answer using a computer algebra system to do the grunt work for me, so importantly you will still need to show your own working yourself.

In brief, your pmf is:

[image]

The cdf $P(X \le x)$ is:

[image]

where `Prob` is a function from the mathStatica add-on to *Mathematica* (I am one of the authors of the former),

and $P(X>3)$ is:

[image]

In response to the suggestion below by robjohn, the `Prob` function calculates symbolic / theoretical solutions to arbitrary probability problems, given an arbitrary user-specified pdf $f(x)$, and it does so by taking advantage of a computer algebra system (in this case *Mathematica*). The solutions produced are exact symbolic solutions - not numerical nor approximate. I believe similar functionality exists for Maple (I am not an author of that software). We have received requests to build a version of mathStatica for Maple, but there is no plan to do so at the present time.

Comment: As a coauthor of mathStatica, you might want to explain what `Prob` does so that it can be simulated elsewhere.

Comment: thanks - of course, it is an exact probability calculator - not a simulator.